# Displaying a section of a html page when a user clicks on the internal link

Tags: javascript, css, html

i am trying to make it easier to navigate an html page that i have created. The links at the begining of the page serve a section jumps. Now i want to hide the DIV contents and remain with the internal links only when someone loads the page, then when the user clicks on an internal link, only the content assosiated with the DIV should be shown to the user. Which scripts should i use?

I also want to include a button that can allow the use to close/hide the content after they finish reading the displayed section and be taken to the main page with internal links.

```
<h3>Antithyroid Drugs</h3>
    <ul>
                <li><a href="#thioamides">Thioamides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#iodine_salts">Iodide Salts and Iodine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#radioactive_iodine">Radioactive Iodine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#anion_inhibitors">Anion Inhibitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#others">Other Drugs</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="thioamides">
    Thioamides
    Methimazole and propylthiouracil (PTU) are small sulfur-containing thioamides that inhibit thyroid hormone synthesis by blocking peroxidase-catalyzed reactions, iodination of the tyrosine residues of thyroglobulin, and coupling of DIT and MIT (Figure 38–1). Propylthiouracil and, to a much lesser extent, methimazole inhibit peripheral conversion of T4 to T3. Because the thioamides do not inhibit the release of preformed thyroid hormone, their onset of activity is usually slow, often requiring 3–4 wk for full effect. The thioamides can be used by the oral route and are effective in young patients with small glands and mild disease. Methimazole is generally preferred because it can be administered once per day. However, PTU is preferred in pregnancy because it is less likely than methimazole to cross the placenta and enter breast milk. Toxic effects include skin rash (common) and severe reactions (rare) such as vasculitis, agranulocytosis, hypoprothrombinemia, and liver dysfunction. These effects are usually reversible.
    </div>

    <div id="iodine_salts">
    Iodide Salts and Iodine
    Iodide salts inhibit iodination of tyrosine and thyroid hormone release (Figure 38–1); these salts also decrease the size and vascularity of the hyperplastic thyroid gland. Because iodide salts inhibit release as well as synthesis of the hormones, their onset of action occurs rapidly, within 2–7 d. However, the effects are transient; the thyroid gland "escapes" from the iodide block after several weeks of treatment. Iodide salts are used in the management of thyroid storm and to prepare patients for surgical resection of a hyperactive thyroid. The usual forms of this drug are Lugol's solution (iodine and potassium iodide) and saturated solution of potassium iodide. Adverse effects include rash, drug fever, metallic taste, bleeding disorders, and, rarely, anaphylactic reactions.
    </div>

    <div id="radioactive_iodine">
    Radioactive Iodine
    Radioactive iodine (131I) is taken up and concentrated in the thyroid gland so avidly that a dose large enough to severely damage the gland can be given without endangering other tissues. Unlike the thioamides and iodide salts, an effective dose of 131I can produce a permanent cure of thyrotoxicosis without surgery. 131I should not be used in pregnant.
    </div>


    <div id="anion_inhibitors">
    Anion Inhibitors
    Anions such as thiocyanate (SCN–) and perchlorate (ClO4–) block the uptake of iodide by the thyroid gland through competitive inhibition of the iodide transporter. Their effectiveness is unpredictable and ClO4– can cause aplastic anemia, so these drugs are rarely used clinically.
    </div>

    <div id="others">
    Other Drugs
    An important class of drugs for the treatment of thyrotoxicosis is the  blockers. These agents are particularly useful in controlling the tachycardia and other cardiac abnormalities of severe thyrotoxicosis. Propranolol also inhibits the peripheral conversion of T4 to T3.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For a pure CSS solution `:target` will work for you.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/TzhPx/)

```
div { display:none; }
div:target { display:block; }
```

As for a show all button, you can augment this CSS with a JavaScript button that will add a class to force the display of all the divs.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8D6YQ/)

**JavaScript**

```
var showAll = document.getElementById('show-all');
showAll.onclick = function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className = 'force-show';
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
div { display:none; }
div:target,
div.force-show { display:block; }
```

### Support

IE8 and below don't support `:target`, if IE8 support is vital then you will probably want to go for more of a JavaScript solution.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/qVuZv/)

```
var showAll = document.getElementById('show-all');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');

showAll.onclick = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className = 'force-show';
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = (function (i) {
        return function () {
            hideAllDivs();
            var linkDiv = document.getElementById(links[i].getAttribute('href').slice(1));
            linkDiv.className = 'force-show';
        }
    })(i);
}

function hideAllDivs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].className = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `:target` does not work on older browsers – so if you hide the content by default, the user might be able to get it visible at all.